# Excel "IF" function has totally stopped working

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

THe "IF" function worked quite well a few months back. Needed to use it again and this time I keep getting the "something's wrong with your formula" window. I've tried everything : changing the commas to semi-colons, using spaces, even using the formula "wizard" - always the same result. THe exact same function works perfectly at home with my laptop - I don't get this at all - Help..

Thanks

OK, your comments and help are welcome - thank you.
I have tried both Excel 2007 which I uninstalled and then 2013 which I installed specifically to see if it changed anything - zip ! Tried pressing control while opening the programme - nothing either.

Concretely, Imagine in column A you have successive numerical entries (the format is "general") 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1. In Column B, I want to simply return 1 if the corresponding adjacent cell in Col A is 1 and 0 otherwise. So accordingly I type "=IF(A1=1 1 0)" (without the quote marks of course) in cell B1 with the intention of filling down. Well after typing this function + arguments, I get the "SOmething wrong with your formula" window. I have tried replacing the space with : commas, commas and a space, semi-colons, semi-colons and a space, changing my keyboard input to different languages, changing the language of my computer - NOTHING WORKS. Right now I'm wondering if there's a bug due to an automatic windows update (aargh).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You question is clear, but it lacks research or effort on your part. Please [edit] your question to include more details like: example of your formula, what version of Excel, are all updates installed, any add-ons being used which might be causing this, have you tried a repair install?

Comment: Hi, OK, I have tried both Excel 2007 which I uninstalled and then Excel 2013 professional. I am not so terribly good at copy pasting screenshots and so on but here goes.

Comment: Could you upload a minimal sample somewhere? That'd be very helpful.

Comment: Do any other formulas work? Try a simple `SUM` formula to see if those work. It would also be helpful to know the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Do you have a localized version of excel in another language than english? Then try the translation of "IF".

Comment: Hi, my Windows is in French, but Excel is installed in English.

Comment: SUM works fine, so do other math operations - I am going to see if this is a generalized problem with all functions requiring more than opne argument and get back. Thanks so much for the help so far.

Comment: CharlieRB, I tried a repair install and even a full re-install - no dice.

Comment: Perhaps my re-install wasn't full enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, answering my own question - here goes.

The problem arises if, like me, you are familiar with Office/Windows in one language but live in a different language zone. In my case I live in "French (switzerland)" and my version of Office is installed in English (UK).

To solve the problem, switch the "format" back to "french (switzerland)" in "control panel"->"clock, language and region (regional settings ?)" -> "modify format [etc..]".

Basically, changing format from native in WIndows leads to problems in Excel.

Thanks for the help.

Y

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the same in Excel's safe mode? Try this:

Hold down the Ctrl key and open excel and then try the "IF" function. Let me know if that works.